# Why there is vertical gap between table and its container-scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Here is JSBin for the problem -
https://jsbin.com/xekehemuno/edit?html,css,output

```
.container {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 5px green solid;
}

.container > table {
  background: #ccc
}
```

When this is opened in Firefox, I see a vertical gap between table and the scrollbar of parent container.
Why there is this gap?

[image]

Comment: This is the default of Firefox. I have checked multiple sites and it seems the same in Firefox.

Comment: It seems fine to me in firefox latest version `70.0.1 (64-bit)`

Comment: @Viral, is ther any way to remove it?

Comment: @Awais, this is observed on Windows OS and FF `70.0.1 (64-bit)`

Comment: But this seems OK to me here is screen shot https://www.screencast.com/t/vofEmCqIj7Jr , I am using same OS and firefox

Comment: @AbhijeetPawar, `scrollbar-width` property might help to you. `scrollbar-width` property allows the author to set the maximum thickness of an element’s scrollbars when they are shown. [Please check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width)

PS: This is an experimental technology [Check the Browser compatibility] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width#Browser_compatibility) table carefully before using this in production